# Open source Android screen orientation locker

Tags: android, open-source, display

I want to lock my Android screen to portrait or landscape very fast, for instance with a widget.

Is there an app for this?

- Free and open source
- Runs at least on Android 4.1

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: Have you checked the quick toggles in your notification bar? I've got one there to disable/enable auto-rotate (Stock LG, ICS). I'm just afraid, on AOSP they've "reverted" the behavior, so they are no longer "quick toggles" but "quick settings" – though some custom ROMs and some manufacturers "adjusted" that again.

Comment: Why do you want to lock your screen orientation?

Answer (score 1):

[PerApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.PerApp)

Change settings like volume, orientation based on the current app.

- Open Source ([source code](https://code.google.com/p/perapp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)), [available at F-Droid too](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=mobi.omegacentauri.PerApp)
- no widget

Comment: I don't believe it is open source. Please link to the source code, thanks!

Comment: Rotation Locker is not open source either.

Comment: Sorry only *per app is open*

Comment: Thanks! Being available at F-Droid is a very good proof that PerApp is open source :-) As Open Source is a hard requirement, I took the liberty to discard the non-open source alternatives, I hope you don't mind, they are still available in the history.

Comment: Actually I added the other thinking there are FOSS. Thanks for adding link, I have a broen  clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

The F-Droid repository includes some tools which may help you.

- [Rotation Lock](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.penghuang.tools.rotationlock): if I recall correctly, this app locks your screen into portrait orientation.
- [Rotation Lock + Landscape](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.cmotc.tools.rotationlockpp): if I recall correctly, this app locks your screen into landscape orientation.

Please don't make Stack Exchange users rely on old memories of mine. Once you try both apps, please edit this post to include current information, and remove this paragraph.